# Starting a 2D array from the middle element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array and i want my second loop to start from the middle element. I should probably type something like x/array.length but i dont know what the x is

Comment: Surely, if you have grid[x][y] where the x and y are both a size that isn't an even number the exact middle is grid[round(x/2)][round(y/2)]. If you've got an even number as your max size then you'll always be slightly out as there is no exact "middle".

Comment: What do you mean by "second loop"? Some code, please.